# pandas to json and dealing with boolean

Tags: json, mongodb, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has True and False, but when I write it to json I get:

```
{"column": false}
```

Then when I eval to store it in mongodb:

`collection.insert_many(eval(json_data)`

I get false undefined. Should I be replacing these false with "False" or not be using eval? When I don't use eval I get an error saying it must be dict, or bson or something.

I used eval to prevent this error:

`document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON,`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like instead of using eval I should be using json.loads()